# Right-Turn-Only Maze

Tags: mazes

I was at a children's park last weekend and wandered upon a tile maze that allows right turns only.

The path is white. The walls are gray. S = start and F = finish.

Can you figure it out?

[image: My recreation of the tile maze]

Comment: I assume that standing in place and making three right turns, such that the net effect is a left turn, would be disallowed? :)

Comment: Similarly, would facing the same direction and walking sideways/backwards be an illegal solution?

Comment: @bobble I wouldn't recommend that answer for deletion, but instead i would enjoy seeing the downvotes pile up on it for being outside the spirit of the question. And as a rule, I don't downvote, but others are not so kind.

Comment: @WoomyRogue There is no trickery in the wording here. It's not a riddle. Go with what you think is clearly intended.

Comment: one strategy, start from F and make left (anti-clockwise) turns until you reach S

Comment: @JLee: I don't think it's clear from the description whether the rule merely requires that one refrain from turning left when some other choice would be available, or whether it also requires that one avoid reaching any corner where the only exit is to the left..  In things like highway codes, a left bend in the road is not considered a "left turn" if there is no other path., but the correct solution to this puzzle would not require entering any passage leading to such corners.

Comment: @supercat I agree, but I gave you what I was given. There was a sign above the maze that read, "Right Turns Only", and like you said, since the solution does not require one to bend left (meaning turn left because the path you are on turns left), then it is a non-issue I think.

Comment: There is definitely a path that requires bend left if you turn right twice immediately from the start, for example. But yeah, it took me some reading of the comments to understand what the puzzle means. Not really the fault of the puzzle I guess, just part of the puzzle to discover what it means.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

> [image]

My method is

> going from F to S, making only left turns. Whenever a route repeats itself (in the same direction), it must be wrong.